How to dockerize and application that spawns many processes?
I have an application from a vendor, which consists of a bunch of binaries and I need to dockerize it for our development lab environment. The application is built such that an "entrypoint" binary launches all those other binaries and exits.
This application's architecture is such that it has a single binary "entrypoint", which creates a shared memory file and launches a bunch of processes that use this file, and then exits. So it cannot be used as the docker process and it can't be used with any kind of init system because it does not launch any bash jobs that could be waited on with wait instruction and if it does keep a list of PIDs somehow, I do not know how.
And when I want to shut everything down, I need to call that entrypoint binary again so it would clean up the shared memory file and kill the processes it launched.
Also, this architecture means that instead of outputting everything to stdout, all those processes write logs to a specific file. As a result I can't track the logs either. I tried to ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /app/log/app.log in the docker image but it doesn't seem to do anything.
I tried to make the following entrypoint but it doesn't work and just hangs there, never exiting:
#!/bin/bash

set -x
dbus-daemon --system --print-address

trap "/opt/app/entrypoint --terminate; exit" 0 SIGINT

su -s /bin/bash app -c "/opt/app/entrypoint $@"
# now it would launch the processes and exit
tail -f /opt/app/logs/app.log

Is there any way that such an application can be containerized or should I reach out to the vendor to change it somehow?

does not fork those other processes, but rather just launches them  That is unclear. You have to use fork to launch a process. If it runs shell, to run shell you have to use fork, and then shell uses fork to run other processes. There are forks everywhere, it is the most basic syscall (clone). just hangs there, never exiting: That's great, means it is "working". How do you know that "never existing" means "doesn't work"?

Because it does not display the contents of the file like it should (and I know the file is not empty because if I replace the tail with cat, it does output the content before exiting) and to exit the "tail" program you can normally use SIGINT, which doesn't work here, in fact the only way to exit the container is to kill it with a docker stop command. And yes, I was unclear with the "doesn't fork" thing, I meant that it's a binary and doesn't launch any bash jobs I could track with a wait -n in the entrypoint script or smth.

I doubt you'll receive any valuable help with ambiguous stuff like "vendor entrypoint" "launches bunch of processes". What vendor? What program is that? What it launches? How it launches? You would have to be more specific. Try tail -F. doesn't launch any bash jobs only bash launches bash jobs. You can wait on any pid with pidwait or tail -f --pid.
